Override EF Core value generators
I want to override the default GuidValueGenerator so it will utilize the Guid.CreateVersion7() method instead of the Guid.NewGuid().
I tried to set the custom value generator for each Guid property iterating over model builder metadata and it works.
public static void SetValueGeneratorOnAdd<T>(this ModelBuilder builder, string columnName, ValueGenerator<T> generator)
{
    var clrType = typeof(T);

    var properties = builder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(
        entity => entity.GetProperties().Where(
            property => property.Name.Equals(columnName, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                     && property.ClrType == clrType));

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        property.ValueGenerated = ValueGenerated.OnAdd;
        property.SetValueGeneratorFactory((prop, type) => generator);
    }
}

But I think replacing the default value generator is much more efficient way.

How I can replace/override default value generator in EF Core on EF model configuring stage?
Maybe there is some kind of service provider for creating EF services or something like that?


"But I think replacing the default value generator is much more efficient way." - why do you think so?

@GuruStron, good question, I pretty much see it as the same thing as overriding virtual members of a class or registering your own implementation of some built in features (e.g. logging) in DI. Overriding the whole thing is more elegant way as for me, rather than having such iteration methods like I provided, which can be quite questionable for future maintainers.

If it is an option, consider using the database to generate the PKs rather than trying to generate them in code. For instance with SQL Server a better performing UUID than NEWID() (like Guid.New()) is NEWSEQUENTIALID().
